# NSMutableArray +tableView+ SQLite

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to:

- Display an NSMutableArray in a UITableView.
- Save and restore the elements in a database.
- Delete rows in the table and keep the changes in sync across the view and the database

Comment: Please don't put your question in a code block, except when it's code of any kind.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this Core Data tutorial](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000085.php). It has everything you are looking for.